# If a theory $T$ has a model that satisfies sentence $s$, does every model of $T$ satisfy $s$?

Tags: logic, model-theory

The question is straightforward as expressed in the title: If a theory $T$ has a model that satisfies sentence $s$, does every model of $T$ satisfy $s$? I think I know the answer as yes, but why this is the case, I cannot find or remember. What would be such proof?

Comment: I would have thought the answer was no. What is $s$ anyway?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown $s$ is a sentence.

Comment: Is $T$ assumed to be complete?

Comment: $D_8$ is a model of the theory of groups and has 8 elements. Not every group has 8 elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer, as stated above, is **no** (unless we assume that $T$ is complete).

If you know a bit of abstract algebra, the simplest natural counterexample to your guess is probably to take $T$ to be the group axioms and $s$ to be the sentence "$\forall x\forall y(x*y=y*x)$." Some but not all groups are abelian, which is to say that some but not all models of $T$ satisfy $s$.

---

Leaving abstract algebra aside, here's a "purely combinatorial" counterexample:

Let $T$ be the empty theory, $T=\emptyset$. Then *every* structure satisfies $T$, vacuously: for $\mathcal{M}$ an arbitrary structure, we have "$\mathcal{M}\models\varphi$ for every $\varphi\in T$" since there *aren't* any $\varphi\in T$ to begin with.

Now consider the sentence $s:=$ "$\exists x\exists y(x\not=y)$." The structures satisfying this sentence are exactlyt he structures with more than one element. Since there are structures which *do* have more than one element, and structures which *don't* have more than one element, that means there are models of $T$ which disagree about whether $s$ is true or false.

Comment: so suppose $T$ is PA (Peano). PA is not complete, if I understand completeness as referring to a theory instead of logic. Then for PA, it is possible that there exists a model that satisfies $s$, while there exists a model that satisfies $\neg s$. Is this correct understanding following from this answer?

Comment: @MullockBrian Yes (I mean, it depends on what $s$ is of course). Completeness of a *logic* says "For every theory $T$ and every sentence $\varphi$, if every model of $T$ satisfies $\varphi$ then $T\vdash\varphi$." Note that completeness isn't really a property of a *logic*, but rather a property of a logic *together with a proof system* (the proof system is *complete with respect to* the logic). A *theory* is complete, by contrast, if for any sentence $\varphi$ it either proves $\varphi$ or proves $\neg\varphi$. (cont'd)

Comment: The completeness theorem (for first-order logic) says that a wide variety of proof systems are complete with respect to first-order logic. Incidentally, the completeness theorem (for a proof system $\mathfrak{p})$ is equivalent to the statement "A theory $T$ is complete (in the sense of $\mathfrak{p}$) iff all its models are elementarily equivalent."